# Stretch bootstrap3 columns by content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my project, there is a text input field and two buttons. The content of one of the buttons is generated dynamically, and sometimes there is VERY LONG CONTENT. The problem is that the button with long content goes too far beyond its boundaries.
How can I make so that the width of the columns was chosen dynamically, depending on the content?
Bootstrap version is 3.4.1

[image]

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="hidden">
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">VERY LONG CONTENT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Очистить</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use overflow you can change the layout using custom classes.
Since bootstrap 3 doesn't support auto columns you don't have many options left. I would suggest using bootstrap 4 or changing your layout with flexbox.

I created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gergana/w3encmLx/) with a simple solution.

You can define the alignment of elements using `justify-content` and `flex` to set
their sizes.

CSS:

```
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.input-group {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
button {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
.btn-primary {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   word-break: break-all; 
}
```

Its helpful code.

Comment: Please have some creativity ;)

Comment: Yes, dear, you can change the structure of your code. please set the search box (col-xs-8) and set button primary (col-xs-3) and button (col-xs-1) that display proper design.